# Stripping a pptx presentation from videos in LibreOffice Impress

Tags: video, libreoffice, pdf

I have a `.pptx` presentation I am editing in LibreOffice Impress. The presentation contains videos. This works fine, but the size of the presentation is quite large because of the videos (177M), which makes it difficult to share and send around. I exported it to pdf, but of course the result suffers from the same problem of size (152M).

I would like to have a lighter version, *without* videos, so that it's easier to share.

Is there a way to export the file so that no videos are included? Other than manually copying the file and removing videos from the copy one by one? I can't find that option while exporting to pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up finding a hack by myself. In fact `.pptx` files are nothing else than zip archives with a specific internal structure and a custom extension. The steps are the following

1. Zip the `.pptx` to a separate folder using `unzip` : `unzip file_in.pptx`
2. Manually remove all MP4 files: `rm *.mp4`
3. Zip everything back again: `zip -r out.pptx *`

To my surprise, the resulting file does not appear to be corrupted and it seems to work perfectly well. Even the videos are replaced by images taken from the videos themselves (I guess the first clip). The PDF export works too. And I did achieve my file size reduction